# R built in Web server

Tags: r

Since R 2.13, R comes with a built-in web server. 
Is there a simple way to create a local web server using R with a custom port number?

In python it will be  (to use "http://localhost:8080") :

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

I'm aware of Rook but I look for a simple solution.

Comment: It is definitely possible but it is hack'ish. It is not a good idea to take something that is supposed to only locally host some helpfiles and assume it is safe to use as a real web-server. I recommend a real web-server.

Comment: Thank's. It is not for real production web apps..just want to run some D3 scripts or use mapnik. It's possible with python but I would like to do this with R

Comment: @eznme do you have a how-to? this would be very useful for the application dickoa specified (running D3 etc)

Comment: I find it interesting that the example in [`r-source/internet/Rhttpd.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/modules/internet/Rhttpd.c#L23) shows clear code ... that does not work (*"there is no .Internal function 'startHTTPD'"*). Bummer, I thought that'd be an easy/good answer.

Comment: @r2evans could it be defined in one of [these](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?q=startHTTPD++in%3A&unscoped_q=startHTTPD++in%3A) files?

Comment: Perhaps not obvious, but I had searched for that and found the same source files. That search you linked is all C files, not providing R functions. So, the sample *R* code written in the top comments of `Rhttpd.c` does not work as given. Are you able to find how to get `.Internal(startHTTPD("127.0.0.1",8080))` to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `Rook` - it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/Rook). About setting a port number, see `?tools::help.ports` it accepts a vector of numbers (integers) and it will choose the first available one. There's also `sinartra` ([CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sinartra/index.html), [GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/sinartra)), but I'd rather go with `Rook`.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like `servr` might be what you're looking for these days.

From [github](https://github.com/yihui/servr):

> To some degree, this package is like python -m SimpleHTTPServer or python -m http.server.

https://github.com/yihui/servr

https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/servr/index.html

#### Example code

```
writeLines("<h1>Hi</H1>", "index.html")

# install.packages("servr")
library(servr)
servr::httd()

# createTcpServer: address already in use
# To stop the server, run servr::daemon_stop(2) or restart your R session
# Serving the directory /Users/st/R/localhost at http://127.0.0.1:7826
```

Place the address in the browser: http://127.0.0.1:7826

Comment: Or just use browseURL("127.0.0...") ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but some places to get started.

If we run R from terminal (by typing `R`), then run `help.start()`, it will start a local host and open it in the browser. On mine, it opens http://127.0.0.1:16371/doc/html/index.html. This at least proves that it's possible to open a localhost in R without any external packages.

I have found some of the code that makes this happen in the [R Source Code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/tools/R/dynamicHelp.R).