# R web server that handles sessions

Tags: r, web-services, webserver

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Please point out to me where if this is the case.

I must build a multi user, stateful (sessions; object persistance) web application that will uses .NET in the backend and must connect to R in order to perform calculations on data that lies in a SQL server 2016 DB. Basically, I need to connect a MS based backend with R.

Everything is clear, except for the problem that I need to find an R server that handles sessions. I know shiny but I can't use it (long story).

rApache and openCPU do not handle sessions.

Rserve for windows is very limited (no parallel connections are supported, subsequent connections share the same namespace and sessions are not supported - this is a consequence of the fact that parallel connections are not supported)

Finally, I have seen Rook (i.e. [Run R/Rook as a web server on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872440/run-r-rook-as-a-web-server-on-startup)) but I can't read anywhere, even the docs. if it is able to deal with sessions. My question is: is there a non stateless R web server or does anyone knows if Rook is stateless?

EDIT:
 Apparently, this question has been around for longer: http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/about#comment-789093732

Comment: If you're using Microsoft R Server, you could consider [R Server operationalisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/operationalize/about)

Comment: Thanks. Just a question: "A compute node is used to execute R code as a session or service". A compute node would open a new child process for every new user?

Comment: I think you can configure that, eg set a limit on how many concurrent sessions can run. You can ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Possibly related/useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59691029/5783745